# Making multiple objects on screen detect a finger sliding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gesture

My goal here is to get a bunch of squares on the screen to detect a sliding finger, and they will only perform their functions when the square in front of it has been slid over. I was wondering if anyone had any good suggestions or ideas to use? I was thinking I would create an `NSMutableArray`, using a struct to contain the points for each square, and then wrap the struct in a `NSValue`then add it to the array. Then I thought I would use a loop to read the array and create all the squares on the screen. But, how do I make the squares detect when a finger slides over them? Do I need to set that in the loop? Does anyone have any suggestions? Sorry, I'm a little new to the iOS game dev. world!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question but I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];

for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]] &&
        CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation))
    {

    }
}
```

}

This will detect anytime one of the onscreen objects is touched. If this doesn't address your question please let me know I will try to modify to better address the issue

Comment: There are also ways to do this without checking the class type but since you are using multiple squares (I'm assuming they are all the same class) I think that using isKindOfClass might be the best route.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry it wasn't clear! The idea is to create a bunch of these squares using the coordinates from the array for their position. Then, I wanted to be able to detect when one is slid over, then it will perform its function. But, the squares can only be slid over in order. For example: square 8 will do nothing if square 1 hasn't already been slid over.

Comment: Is there a way I could check variables on the object being slid over? For example: if (theSlidOverObject.aValue = something) { } else {}?

Comment: I'm sure you could just place the objects into the array in order. Then if the touched object is next in the array do thing1 else do thing2. I have code for this @ home but I'm @ work right now :/ I'll try to remember tonight or find something during lunch.

Comment: Okay, that would be really helpful! Thanks!